# How to update tuples array in Swift?

Tags: swift

I have one tuple array for

e.g. `[(Student, Bool)]` and other `Bool` array as `[true, false, false]`

I want to update tuple bool value as per bool array, for example:

```
var tupleArray = [("first", true), ("second", false ), ("third", true)]
var boolArray = [true, false, false]
```

Result should be:

```
var tupleArray = [("first", true), ("second", false ), ("third", false)]
```

Is there any best way to achieve this?

Comment: `var boolArray =["true", "false", "false"]` is `var boolArray =[true, false, false]` instead? Meaning, bool values and not string ones?

Comment: @Larme yes you are right my mistake ..updated question

Comment: Did you try something? Like a simple for loop? With `i` being the index, `tupleArray[i] = (tupleArray[i].0, boolArray[i])`

Comment: I am wondering if there is any higher order function?

Comment: `zip(tupleArray.map { $0.0 }, boolArray)`

Comment: Consider this Apple comment: *Tuples are useful for simple groups of related values. They’re not suited to the creation of complex data structures. If your data structure is likely to be more complex, model it as a class or structure, rather than as a tuple.*

Comment: What should happen if the array sizes don't match?

Comment: @vadian I would say that OP uses tuples as apple describes it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```swift
zip(tupleArray, boolArray).map { ($0.0, $1) }
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution is to enumerate and use `map`

```
tupleArray = tupleArray.enumerated().map { ($1.0, boolArray[$0]) }
```

Or use `zip` as mentioned in the comments

```
tupleArray = Array(zip(tupleArray.map { $0.0 }, boolArray))
```

If the arrays are of different size or rather if `tupleArray` is longer than `boolArray` we have an issue, the first code will crash and the second will only include the same number of elements from `tupleArray` as exists in `boolArray`

To fix the first code we could use the original value from `tupleArray`

```
tupleArray = tupleArray.enumerated()
    .map { ($1.0, $0 < boolArray.count ? boolArray[$0] : $1.1) }
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use the next trick for that:

```
var tupleArray = [("first", true), ("second", false ), ("third", true)]
print(tupleArray)
var boolArray = [true, false, false]

for i in 0...(tupleArray.count - 1) {
    tupleArray[i].1 = boolArray[i]
}

print(tupleArray)
```

Result will be next:

```
[("first", true), ("second", false), ("third", true)]
[("first", true), ("second", false), ("third", false)]
```

Comment: This is just bad code. When the array is empty, it will even crash.